# Adding text inside 2 different Doughuts chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two charts, each one will diplay data for a month with a title that shows witch month it is that the chart is showing. But it shows title for both months in both Charts, On Eachother.
I wonder if anyone did manage to display the wanted text in the middle of the right Chart.    [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RajaaG/z7krtz26/1/)

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>

<script type="javascript">
    var data = {
        labels: [
            "White",
            "Blue",
            "Yellow"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: ["#FFF", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FFF", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"]
        }]
    };

    var DeliveryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        elementById: ('myChart'),
        data: data,
        options: {responsive: true, legend: {display: false}}
    });

    Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var width = chart.chart.width, height = chart.chart.height, ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            ctx.restore();

            var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
            ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

            var text = "Oktober",
                textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                textY = height / 2;
            ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
            ctx.save();
        }
    });

    var data = {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"]
        }]
    };

    var promisedDeliveryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart1'), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        elementById: ['myChart1'],
        data: data,
        options: {responsive: true, legend: {display: false}}
    });

    Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var width = chart.chart.width,
                height = chart.chart.height,
                ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            ctx.restore();

            var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
            ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

            var text = "November",
                textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                textY = height / 2;
            ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
            ctx.save();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you're registering two beforeDraw functions. These are not bound to a particular chart. If you want the text to refer to data from your chart, you're going to have to update it to use data in the chart object.

To do this, I've added title to the options you pass in (this has the disadvantage of displaying a title on each doughnut, but you can probably work around that). Then the onDraw function uses that title text to display in the centre of the doughnut.

```
var promisedDeliveryChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart1'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  elementById:['myChart1'],
  data: data2,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'November'
        }
  }
});




Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    console.log (chart.options.title.text);
    var text = chart.options.title.text;
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
  }
});
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxo6gmcn/).